# Updating collection through model without creating new rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

In my MVC3 application I have a bunch of "SubscriptionTariffs" each of which is related to a number of "SubscriptionServices". I have created a view to be able to edit these Tariffs and also edit the collection being passed through the model of the Services.

The problem is, that whenever I submit the form, rather than editing the existing services in the database, it creates a new row for every service attached.

Here is my controller's method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function Edit
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subscriptionViewModel"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SubscriptionViewModel subscriptionViewModel)
    {
        if (subscriptionViewModel == null) throw new ArgumentException("The value of subscriptionViewModel cannot be null.", "subscriptionViewModel");

        Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogDebug("SubscriptionController Edit: Method entered.");

        using (_ownerManager)
        {
            var mappedSubscription = Mapper.Map<SubscriptionTariff>(subscriptionViewModel);
            _ownerManager.SaveSubscription(mappedSubscription);
        }

        Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogDebug("SubscriptionController Edit: Method exited.");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And a section of the manager which should be running the queries on the database:

```
    var userTariff = (from s in this.Database.SubscriptionTariffs 
                                  where s.SubscriptionTariffId.Equals(subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionTariffId) 
                                  select s).FirstOrDefault();

    userTariff.SubscriptionTariffId = subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionTariffId;
    userTariff.Name = subscriptionTariff.Name;
    userTariff.Description = subscriptionTariff.Description;
    userTariff.IsActive = subscriptionTariff.IsActive;
    userTariff.PricePerMonth = subscriptionTariff.PricePerMonth;
    userTariff.CurrencyCode = subscriptionTariff.CurrencyCode;
    userTariff.PaymentServiceProvider = subscriptionTariff.PaymentServiceProvider;
    userTariff.IncomingMaxTransactionPerMonth = subscriptionTariff.IncomingMaxTransactionPerMonth;
    userTariff.OutgoingMaxTransactionPerMonth = subscriptionTariff.OutgoingMaxTransactionPerMonth;

    userTariff.SubscriptionServices = subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionServices;

    this.Database.SaveChanges();
    Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogDebug("SaveSubscription method exited");
    return subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionTariffId;
```

The tariff is updating fine, but I can't get the services to update. If someone could give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Might also be helpful including the ViewModel!

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public int SubscriptionTariffId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public decimal PricePerMonth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string PaymentServiceProvider { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the outgoing max transaction per month.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The outgoing max transaction per month.</value>
    public int OutgoingMaxTransactionPerMonth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the incoming max transaction per month.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The incoming max transaction per month.</value>
    public int IncomingMaxTransactionPerMonth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<SubscriptionService> SubscriptionServices { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of

```
userTariff.SubscriptionServices = subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionServices;
```

Please try

```
subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionServices.ToList().ForEach(ss =>
    {
        // get the instance of the correct subscriptionTariff using the
        // id (IdOfSubscriptionServices)
        var u = userTariff.SubscriptionServices.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IdOfSubscriptionServices == ss.IdOfSubscriptionServices);

        if (u != null)
        {
            // update each property
            u.Prop1 = ss.Prop1;
            u.Prop2 = ss.Prop2;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, unfortunately I am getting a few errors with this. Please see the screenshot below:

http://gyazo.com/59677cfc429f15f80891fa6b1a008893

Unfortunately, I'm fair new to development so I'm not 100% on what to do here but any help would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Ooopps.. sorry my mistake mate.. can you pls try replacing **userTariff.SubscriptionServices.ToList(** with **userTariff.SubscriptionServices.ToList().ForEach(**. I dont have a code editor with me, so pls let me know if you encounter any other compilation errors

Comment: And pls make sure you have System.Linq namespace included

Comment: No need to apologise, I just appreciate your help mate! This is getting closer, no build errors, the loop is working and I can see the properties being mapped in the manager. However the changes are no getting replicated in my database. Would you have any idea why this might be the case? No errors are getting thrown, it just isn't updating. Thanks again for your ongoing help!

Comment: Please see the screenshot for my code. I made the changes you suggested but my database still isn't getting updated, can you see any glaring errors in my changes? gyazo.com/939f983e40037a8bec735ee2cfab5309 Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Nick, maybe I have got the problem by the tails end. In the code, we are updating subscriptionTariff using userTariff. But I think it should be the other way around. Can you please swap userTariff with subscriptionTariff and let me know how it goes? Cheers

Comment: Hi Chintana, can I just clarify where you mean?

userTariff.SubscriptionTariffId = subscriptionTariff.SubscriptionTariffId;
.
.
.
userTariff.OutgoingMaxTransactionPerMonth = subscriptionTariff.OutgoingMaxTransactionPerMonth;

These fields that are unique to to the SubscriptionTariffs are all updating in the database, so I just want to make sure I know where I'm tinkering about!

Sorry if my responses seem to be little issues, but I appreciate your time in helping me sort this out.

Comment: Hi Nick, pls have a look at the edited answer and let me know .. cheers

Comment: Chintana, you are my hero. Honestly can't say how much I appreciate your help with this, haha. The solution is now working a charm! Cheers mate!

Comment: Gr8 to know that it worked mate .. sorry for not getting it right the first time .. Cheerse